# Stacked icons not actually centered

Tags: html, css, sass, frontend, font-awesome

Good afternoon everyone, I am working on a navigation bar for my website and as you know, the responsiveness is very important and therefore I want the spacing to be perfect on mobile.

To be exact, I am working on a shopping cart with the item count using the FontAwesome's stacked icons technique, I've partly used some code I have found online, but I noticed that the shopping cart icon is slightly aligned off of the center, this sucks for the navigation bar on mobile screens when I want to use equal spacing.

This is the HTML:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <span class="fa-stack fa-2x has-badge" :data-count="totalItems" @click="showCart" >
        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
        <i style="" class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-stack-1x red-cart"></i>
    </span>
</li>
```

And here is the SCSS:

```
$shopping-cart-red: #495057;

.fa-stack[data-count]:after{
  position:absolute;
  right:0.7em;
  margin-left:auto;
  top:0.3em;
  content: attr(data-count);
  font-size:40%;
  padding:0.4em;
  border-radius:999px;
  line-height:.75em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  color:$shopping-cart-red;
  text-align:center;
  min-width:2em;
  font-weight:bold;
  border:solid;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
.fa-circle {
  color:#495057;
}

.red-cart {
    color: #495057; background:#FFFFFF;
    //margin-top:-1px;
}
```

JSFiddle link to the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lo17ha8w/

Here is the full preview on my site because I don't know how else to put it on JSFiddle:
https://gyazo.com/d28c9710cec210d9416cbc607e02d385

Full code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white" v-if="shopInfo">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="navbar-collapse dual-nav collapse">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav telAndMail mt-2 mt-lg-0 w-100 p-jc-start">
                            <li class="nav-item p-pr-1">
                                <i class="pi pi-phone nav-link"><span class="p-component p-ml-2">{{shopInfo.tel_nr}}</span></i>
                            </li>             
                            <li class="nav-item p-pl-1 p-pr-1">
                                <i class="pi pi-envelope nav-link p-pr-1"><span class="p-component p-ml-2">{{shopInfo.email}}</span></i>
                            </li>
                        </ul>                   
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 p-text-right navbar-collapse collapse dual-nav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mt-2 mt-lg-0 w-100 p-jc-end">
                        <li class="nav-item p-pr-1 p-pl-0">
                            <span class="p-component">Our showroom</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item p-pl-1 p-pr-1">
                            <span class="p-component">Helpdesk</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white p-mb-3">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-nav">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse dual-nav w-25 shop-image">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-item active">
                                <router-link :to="{ name: 'home' }"><img v-if="shopInfo" class="navbar-brand mx-auto d-block w-75" :src="'/shop/' + shopInfo.image" :alt="shopInfo.name" /></router-link>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <div class="nav-link">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav mt-2 mt-lg-0 w-100 p-jc-center search-section">
                            <li class="nav-item p-pl-1 p-pr-1 w-25 search-dropdown">
                                <Dropdown v-model="selectedCategory" :options="categories" optionLabel="name" class="w-100" placeholder="Select a Category" />
                            </li>             
                            <li class="nav-item p-pl-1 p-pr-1 w-50 search-autocomplete">
                                <AutoComplete v-model="selectedProduct" :suggestions="filteredProducts" @complete="searchProduct($event)" placeholder="Search for a Product">
                                    <template #item="slotProps">
                                        <img :alt="slotProps.item.product_image[0].name" :src="'/products/' + slotProps.item.product_image[0].image" width="50px" height="50px" />
                                        <div>{{slotProps.item.name}}</div>
                                    </template>
                                </AutoComplete>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item p-pl-1 p-pr-1 w-10 search-button">
                                <Button label="Search" class="w-100"  />
                            </li>
                        </ul>                   
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 p-text-right shopping-cart">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mt-2 mt-lg-0 w-100 p-jc-end">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <span class="fa-stack fa-2x has-badge" :data-count="totalItems" @click="showCart" >
                                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                <i style="" class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-stack-1x red-cart"></i>
                            </span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-link" v-if="isLoggedIn" @click="logout">
                            <Button v-if="isLoggedIn" icon="pi pi-sign-in" label="Log out" class="p-button-raised p-button-danger p-button-rounded"/>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- <div><li class="nav-link" v-if="isLoggedIn" @click="logout"><Button v-if="isLoggedIn" icon="pi pi-sign-in" label="Log out" class="p-button-raised p-button-danger p-button-rounded"/></li></div>
                    <Button :disabled="totalItems == '0'" icon="pi pi-shopping-cart" id="body" class="p-button-raised p-button-rounded p-button-secondary ml-auto" :label="String(totalItems)" @click="showCart" /> -->
                    <OverlayPanel ref="op" appendTo="body" :showCloseIcon="true" id="overlay_panel" style="width: 550px">
                        <DataTable :value="cart">
                            <template #header>
                            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">{{totalItems}}</span>
                                {{formatCurrency(totalPrice)}}
                            </li>
                            </template>
                            <Column field="name">
                                <template #body="slotProps">
                                    {{slotProps.data.name}}
                                </template>
                            </Column>
                            <Column>
                                <template #body="slotProps">
                                    <img :src="'/products/' + slotProps.data.image" :alt="slotProps.data.image" class="product-image" />
                                </template>
                            </Column>
                            <Column field="price">
                                <template #body="slotProps">
                                    {{formatCurrency(slotProps.data.subtotal)}}
                                </template>
                            </Column>
                            <Column field="quantity" class="cartArrows">
                                <template #body="slotProps">
                                    <div class="p-grid mt-0 p-0">
                                        <div class="p-col-9 mt-0 mb-0">
                                            <InputNumber v-model="slotProps.data.quantity" inputClass="amountItem" decrementButtonClass="decreaseAmount" incrementButtonClass="increaseAmount" showButtons @input="changeQuantityItem(slotProps.data)" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="p-col-3 mt-0 mb-0">
                                            <Button v-model="slotProps.data.id" class="p-button-rounded p-button-danger deleteFromCartBtn p-col-6" icon="pi pi-times" @click="removeFromCart(slotProps.data)" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </template>
                            </Column>
                        </DataTable>

                        <router-link :to="{ name: 'cart' }" v-if="user_type == 0 || user_type == 1"><Button class="p-button-raised float-right m-2" @click="showCart()">Checkout</Button></router-link>
                    </OverlayPanel>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <main class="py-0">
            <Toast position="top-right">{{error}}</Toast>
            <router-view @loggedIn="change"></router-view>
        </main>
    </div>
</template>
```

Scoped style:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
::v-deep .p-autocomplete, ::v-deep .p-autocomplete > input {
    width:100%;
}
.navbar:nth-child(2) {
    box-shadow: rgb(30 50 93 / 25%) 0px 0px 5px -1px, rgb(0 0 0 / 30%) 0px 1px 3px -1px;
}
::v-deep .p-overlaypanel::after, .p-overlaypanel:before {
 background:none !important;
 border:none !important;
}
::v-deep .p-datatable-thead {
    display:none;
}
::v-deep .p-overlaypanel-close {
    z-index:1;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    ::v-deep .p-autocomplete, ::v-deep .p-autocomplete > input {
        width: auto;
    }
    .search-autocomplete {
        width:100%!important;
    }
    .search-dropdown, .shop-image, .search-button {
        display:none;
        width:0px!important;
        position: absolute!important; 
        left: -999em!important;
    }
    .search-section { 
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    .navbar > .container-fluid {
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
    }
    .navbar > .container-fluid > .col-lg-2{
        padding: 0;
    }
    .navbar > .container-fluid > .col-lg-8,  .navbar > .container-fluid > .col-lg-8 > .nav-link {
        padding:0;
    }
    .nav-item > .fa-stack[data-count]:after {
        right: 0.2em;
    }
    .nav-item > .fa-stack {
        width:2.1em;
    }
}
</style>
```

And also, of course the width of the burger icon and the shopping cart are quiet different. What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: At a glace the shopping cart is centered. It just look a bit off since the full width of the cart is used when centering, the handle bars are included too. The stacked circle isn't accounted for though.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use Bootstrap's `flex` layout like `justify-content-center`.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content

I am not sure if that'd work, but FontAwesome's icons are not 100% aligned as what you'd like them to. After all, they are simply image icons.